# When accessing a resource on website a forward slash gets removed from url when redirecting to https

Tags: django, web, nginx, url

I have an Nginx serving my django application. When I try to access example.com/resource it should redirect to https://example.com/resource but in my case it redirects to https://example.comresource (removing the / before resource)

I have a very minimal Nginx configuration (as you'll see below). I don't know where to start to figure out what's wrong.

```
server{
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example_com.key;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/administrator/example/collectedstatic/;
    }

    location /media {
            alias /home/administrator/example/store;
    }



}



server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/administrator/example/collectedstatic/;
    }

    location /media {
            alias /home/administrator/example/store;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

There are no error messages, just a webpage not found.

Comment: But nothing here is even listening to :80, let alone redirecting to 443. Where is that configured?

Comment: this is in a virtual machine, so I'm not listening to port 80

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question is. **Exactly** what URL are you accessing before the redirect?

Comment: example.com/resources but that redirects to https://example.comresources without the /

Comment: @DanielRoseman SOLVED: It was my mistake, I was looking at the configuration file in the virtual machine and not at the configuration file that redirects all traffic to my virtual machine. Missed a trailing / in the virtual host configuration for port 80. I don't have access to that configuration, I have to talk to someone that has. Thanks for your help